# How to extend/customize the Named Entity in NLTK/StanfordNLP/CoreNlP？

Tags: nltk, stanford-nlp, data-mining, information-retrieval, named-entity-recognition

I've used NLTK to recognize the raw text and I found the predefined NER is so limited such as:

- PER for person
- ORG for organization

How can I expand this limited NE to a more comprehensive one like

- PSY for psychology
- CHE for chemistry *etc.*

In what format should I write the dataset and which path should I put it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can train a new model with training data in this format.

```
Joe    PERSON
Smith  PERSON
went   O
to     O
France LOCATION
.
```

Note that is a tab delimited file with the token on the left, a tab, and the NER tag on the right.  You would replace this with your specialized tags.  Models are usually trained on thousands of sentences.

This file is a good example of the properties to use to train a model:

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/scripts/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.prop

This is the command to train the model (make sure your CLASSPATH is set properly)

```
java -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop english.all.3class.distsim.prop
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,that helps a lot,Can I make a dataset in this format? <br/>IBM COM <br/>Microsoft COM <br/> Goggle COM<br/> I mean the whole list tag is COM like a dictionary

Comment: At that point you don't really want to train a model, you just want direct look up.  Look at https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/regexner.html for more info.